# Binding predefined state to checkboxes using ko.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, knockout.js

I want to apply predefined states to checkboxes using knockout.js
I've already tried dozens of things, but cant get this working.

This is my code:

```js
function DemoItem(id, name, state) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.Name = ko.observable(name);
  self.Selected = ko.observable(state);
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.availableItems = ko.observableArray([]);


  self.init = function() {
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(1, 'One', true));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(2, 'Two', true));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(3, 'Three', false));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(4, 'Four', true));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(5, 'Five', true));
  };

  self.relayState = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.availableItems, function(item) {
        return item.Selected();
      });

    },
    write: function(value) {
      if (value) {
        console.log("associate item ");
      } else {
        console.log("disasociate item ");
      }
    }
  })
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init();
```

```html
Available Items:
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id(), checked: $root.relayState" />
  <span data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + Name()"></span>
  <br/>
</div>
```

I cant get checkboxes to initially apply predefined values.

This is the link to JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w392rpxf/

Comment: What is the purpose of your relayState computed function? If you bypass that and bind your checkboxes directly to the DemoItem model with "checked: Selected" the predefined values work correctly. `relayState` is the issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it without knowing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I need to be able to also control individual checkboxes by  sending the toggled checkbox to a function which then binds it to checked or unchecked state. So basically I first want to check or uncheck checkboxes depending on predefined state, and then manualy control them and transfer their state to a fubction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but it sounds like knockout's regular bindings should have you covered.

You can create an `observableArray` that holds the selections. (Un)checking any checkbox automatically adds or removes an item to/from this array.

The `Selected` property on your `DemoItem` is only used to fill its initial state in the init function.

```js
function DemoItem(id, name, state) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.Name = ko.observable(name);
  self.Selected = ko.observable(state);
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.availableItems = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([]);

  // Log changes to the console
  self.selectedItems.subscribe(function(sel) {
    console.log("Selected are: " + sel.map(function(s) {
      return s.Name();
    }).join(", "));
  });

  self.init = function() {
    self.availableItems([
      new DemoItem(1, 'One', true),
      new DemoItem(2, 'Two', true),
      new DemoItem(3, 'Three', false),
      new DemoItem(4, 'Four', true),
      new DemoItem(5, 'Five', true)
    ]);
    
    // Set up the initial state
    self.selectedItems(
      self.availableItems()
        .filter(function(item) {
          return item.Selected();
        })
    );
  };
  
  

}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
Available Items:
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.selectedItems, checkedValue: $data" />
  <span data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + Name()"></span>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Edit: since you want to know which one changed, here's another example:

```js
function DemoItem(id, name, state, onChange) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.Name = ko.observable(name);
  self.Selected = ko.observable(state);
  
  self.Selected.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    onChange(self, newValue);
  });
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.availableItems = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedItems = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.availableItems().filter(function(demoItem) {
      return demoItem.Selected();
    });
  });

  // Log changes to the console
  self.selectedItems.subscribe(function(sel) {
    console.log("Selected are: " + sel.map(function(s) {
      return s.Name();
    }).join(", "));
  });
  
  // Log the individual that caused the change
  self.onItemChange = function(item, newValue) {
    console.log("The item that changed was " + item.Name() + " (" + newValue + ")");
  };

  self.init = function() {
    self.availableItems([
      new DemoItem(1, 'One', true, self.onItemChange),
      new DemoItem(2, 'Two', true, self.onItemChange),
      new DemoItem(3, 'Three', false, self.onItemChange),
      new DemoItem(4, 'Four', true, self.onItemChange),
      new DemoItem(5, 'Five', true, self.onItemChange)
    ]);
  };
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
Available Items:
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Selected" />
  <span data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + Name()"></span>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, hope I can now explain what I want to do.
I want  to set initial states using relayState read. After that I want to know the exact checkbox that is being checked or unchecked, and then log that with console.log() in the relayState write

Comment: I've included another example that does exactly what you describe. Again, I don't think you need a writable computed.

Comment: can it be done with writeable computed? If yes, how?
Thank you for your answers so far

Comment: Probably, but I don't see the point in trying it. Is your question about solving the problem, or are you just trying to learn more about writeable computeds? Because I think this isn't the right use case for them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Could you please explain what is the right use case for writeable computeds?

Comment: Also one more question. How can I control whether the checkboxes will be initialized with their initial value of to unchecked state with another boolean variable? Whats is the neates way to do this?

Comment: Writeable computed are most often used when you want the values you *store* to be slightly different from the values you *input/output*. For example: A user enters `"100"` in an input field, I want to store this as `100`, and display it as `$100.00`.

Comment: You're already passing the initial checked states to the `DemoItem` constructor. If you want them to be initialized differently, you'd pass them another initial value.

Comment: Let me explain better, I want to have a new boolean named latch. If latch is true, then apply initial state, if latch is false, apply default unchecked states

Comment: In `init`, after creating the items: `if (!latch) self.availableItems().forEach(x => x.Selected(false))`